# Is there a way to find out if a pdf file is signed by someone (not digitally signed)?

Tags: pdf

We have thousands of pdf documents on our network with most of them being signed PDFs, not the digital kind but a proper signature and scanned pdf in one of the pages.

Is there a way to find out if a pdf file is signed or not signed?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to find out if a PDF contains an image that is a scan of any handwritten signature of any of a large unknown number of people.

If the image of the signature is always the same image and not a rescan of a newly made real signature then you could checksum each image in the PDF and compare the checksum with the single reference image or with a set of checksums.

This would require some software development (or at least scripting) using a PDF toolkit. So the details are likely to depend not only on the signature process but on the PDF generation tools and on the programming language expertise available.

Since such scans of signatures are something of a security joke and an invitation to forgery, there is little reason to do this. Digital signatures make much more sense.